# Loopback API Connection to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, loopbackjs

I created an API using Loopback, and had it working great with a MongoDB on LocalHost. I am now trying to switch it over to use MongoDB Atlas (online).

I ran `lb datasource` and filled everything in, and now this is my `datasources.json` file:

```
{
  "db": {
    "host": "fishapi-cxtvd.mongodb.net",
    "port": 0,
    "url": "mongodb+srv://admin:********@fishapi-cxtvd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "database": "admin",
    "password": "********",
    "name": "MyMongoDB",
    "user": "admin",
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

I have also tried reformatting it (as suggested on a different stack overflow question), so it looks like this:

```
{
  "db": {
    "url": "mongodb+srv://admin:********@fishapi-cxtvd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "name": "FishAPI",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

This is the error I receive whenever I run it:

```
MongoParseError: Cannot create data source "db": Cannot initialize connector "mongodb": URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I need to change to get this properly connected? Any help is appreciated as this is my first time using Loopback, and MongoDB!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of `loopback-connector-mongodb`?

The error message suggests that the connector (or the underlying MongoDB client library) is not able to parse `url`. Perhaps the schema `mongodb+srv://` is not supported by the version you are using?

As far as I can tell, support for `mongodb+srv://` URLs was added relatively recently (in April 2019), see the pull request https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/497. The change was released in May as part of `loopback-connector-mongodb@4.2.0`. Please upgrade your project to use the latest connector version.

Alternatively, you can try to use `mongodb://` instead. According to [this MongoDB blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-3-6-here-to-SRV-you-with-easier-replica-set-connections), `mongodb+srv` was added in version 3.6 to simplify the configuration of a seed list used to connect to a cluster of MongoDB servers. According to the post, it should be possible to replace `mongodb+srv://` URL containing a single host with  `mongodb://` URL containing multiple hosts.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up solving my issue by changing the name parameter to db (the default loopback name parameter). For clarity to anyone else looking here, I used my reformatted version with only the name, url, and connector parameters.